# AudioRecord fails on outgoing Call?

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

Could not get audio input for record source 1 
: ERROR/AuthorDriver(34): Command 14 completed with error -1
ERROR/MediaRecorder(363): start failed: -1
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

Getting rror Like this Please Help Me.Its Urgent.todays my submission in college.Plz help me.As soon as possible.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework.

Comment: i am asking You whats the issue?How can I resolve it